# DataGridView will not update unless the application is restarted

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

Working in Visual Studio 2012 for C#; and I'm trying to implement a dataGridView. I am using another part of the program to add records to an Access Database, which the dataGridView uses to populate its information.

I used the integrated setup, so it takes away a lot of the work as far as making the connection. Everything works fine, but the dataGridView won't show the most recent changes to the database unless I close the application and restart it. Once the app is restarted, everything works fine and the list populates correctly. I've tried refreshing the database as well as changing the data source to null then back to the actual source, and neither have worked thus far.

Ideas?

Can provide code as needed.

Edit: Code as requested:

```
    public void frmViewBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = this.accDB.BOOK;

        this.bOOKTableAdapter.Fill(this.accDB.BOOK);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read the [faq]'s and [ask]. We need to see your code, it sounds like you are not refreshing the DataGridView's datasource after adding new records to the Access DB.

Comment: There is an event called row_updated this is where you will bind the datagrid to show the updated values. Everything in the grid happens in events.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing the updating manually and not using the built-in capabilities of the GridView then you will need to call `DataBind()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I made a new method "load" to clear the rows value of my datagridview and create datagridview again. So I put the method "load" every time that I add/edit the datagridview.